# What are the advantages or difference in “assert False” and “self.assertFalse”

Tags: python, assert, unit-testing

I am writing tests and I have heard some people saying to use [`self.assertFalse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertFalse) rather than [`assert False`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/simple_stmts.html#assert). Why is this and are there any advantages to be had?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`assert False` throws an exception without useful logging information.  The test had an error.

`self.assertFalse()` throws a test failure exception with test failure information like a message and a test name.

There's a difference between an error -- test could not even run -- and a failure -- test code worked but produced the wrong answer.

Errors are a serious problem with your code.

Failures are just failures that need to be fixed.

Comment: Thanks, that makes useful to know, I'll need to remove the `assert False` lines. +1

Comment: Hi, this is apparently wrong.  The test runner should (and does) catch `AssertionError` and report them correctly as test failures.

Comment: You can add some useful information to assert False, like this ```assert False, "INFO" ```

Answer (score 46):

If you run

```
import unittest

class Test_Unittest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_assert(self):
        assert False
    def test_assertFalse(self):
        self.assertFalse(True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

You get the same logging information, the same failure:

```
FF
======================================================================
FAIL: test_assert (__main__.Test_Unittest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/unutbu/pybin/test.py", line 6, in test_assert
    assert False
AssertionError

======================================================================
FAIL: test_assertFalse (__main__.Test_Unittest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/unutbu/pybin/test.py", line 8, in test_assertFalse
    self.assertFalse(True)
AssertionError

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

FAILED (failures=2)
```

The reason both are handled the same is because `unittest.TestCase` defines

```
failureException = AssertionError
```

When you say `assert False` an AssertionError is raised.

When you say `self.assertFalse(True)`, a `failureExeception` is raised.

Since these exceptions are the same, there is no apparent difference.

`assert` and `self.assertFalse` do differ in conventional usage, however.

`assert` is used to declare that a certain condition should hold at a certain point in the code. It is used as a crutch during development, but is not meant to be used in production code. If you run `python -O my_unittest.py`, all assert statements are ignored. That would subvert your intended usage of `assert`, possibly making your unit tests pass even when there is a failure.

Even though (without the -O flag) the result is the same, `assert` is not meant to be used in unit test code. Use `self.assertTrue` or `self.assertFalse` when writing unit tests.

Comment: instead of using `self.assertFalse(True)` you can (and probably should) use `self.fail()`.

Answer (score 12):

One point the answers so far have failed to mention is that there are several test frameworks (e.g. [py.test](http://codespeak.net/py/dist/test/) and [nose](http://code.google.com/p/python-nose/)) that use python's introspection magic to allow you to write unit tests like so:

```
# test_this_and_that.py
def test_frobber():
    assert frobber('x') == 'y'
# EOF
```

without requiring any of the unittest boilerplate you saw above. So in some cases it can boil down to just a framwork/stylistic issue.