# assert vs == for testing code in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, testing, tdd

What is the need for importing unittest and running assertTrue (for example) while testing a python function instead of writing a usual python function with == True check for testing? What is the new thing about unittesting, as even the test cases have to be written by user, which can be checked by == instead of assert family of functions in unittest? My question basically is: assert in unittest vs the equality check operation == in Python.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do assertions in unittest use TestCase.assertEqual not the assert keyword?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6361147/why-do-assertions-in-unittest-use-testcase-assertequal-not-the-assert-keyword)

Comment: Nope. My question was about assert in unittest vs the general equality check operation == in Python.

Comment: You use asserts to define expected behaviour. If the assert fails, the test will fail. E.g. `assertTrue(3 < 4, 'Operator < does not work.')`. Operator `==` does no such thing by itself. It just returns True or False.

Comment: Can't I just print that the test failed when == operator returned False? What's the big deal then about assert? (Novice here, thanks!) @zvone

Comment: You can print if you have one or tests which you run manually when you want to test. But if you have 1000 tests which run automatically every then, then you don't want to read the prints - with asserts, unittest knows which tests failed and then you could e.g. configure the system to send you emails when a test fails.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the most interesting thing is the "easy-to-test" that the unittest package (as well as others, for example pytest) provides. When using unittest you can just run a command and check if your refactoring or your last feature broke something on the rest of the program. I would read something about [test-driven development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) to understand better what is the importance of unittesting.